# How to copy contents of direct ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, memory

Why does this does not work?

If you inspect the backing array of tt, all values are 0 whereas bb is the sequence of 1-100
And why is the system.out not identical at the end?

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(100);
for(int i =0;i< 100; i++) {
  bb.put(new Byte(""+i));
}
ByteBuffer tt = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(100);
tt.put(bb);

for(int i =0;i< 100; i++) {
       System.out.println("BACKED bb" + bb.get(i));
       System.out.println("BACKED tt" + tt.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean "does not work"? What do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Do you get an exception?  What line?  (And why are you converting the integer to a string, parsing it to a byte, boxing it, and then unboxing it instead of writing `bb.put((byte) i)`?

Comment: If you want to inspect the contents, you shouldn't be using a direct `ByteBuffer` in the first place. They are for cases where you want to keep the data on the JNI side, for example copying between channels. If you need the data in the Java side, use a normal `ByteBuffer.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `put(byte)` increments the current position, so when it tries to read `bb` to put the results into `tt`, it is reading from the end of the buffer.

To do what you want, you want something like:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(100);
for(int i =0;i< 100; i++) {
  bb.put((byte)i);
}
ByteBuffer tt = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(100);
// reset the position so that we can copy it to the new ByteBuffer.
// Could also call bb.rewind() here. 
bb.position(0);
tt.put(bb);

for(int i =0;i< 100; i++) {
       System.out.println("BACKED bb" + bb.get(i));
       System.out.println("BACKED tt" + tt.get(i));
}
```

As an aside, I have changed the creation slightly, there is no need to create a string to get the byte value, just cast the int straight to a byte.

Comment: @hunterp rewind() the buffer.

Comment: @hunterp no problems… glad to help. As an aside, I have also updated the answer slightly to not create the Byte object, as that is not needed.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this:

```
bb.put((new Byte(""+i)).byteValue());
```

Comment: This isn't needed, since auto-boxing will take care of that conversion for you.

Comment: In fact the Byte class is completely unnecessary. `bb.put((byte)i);` should be sufficient.